# Collecting Duplicate Column names from multiple DataFrames Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-modeling

Essentially I am trying to create a list so that I can merge my Dataframes on Column names that are duplicated. Below is how I am currently set up.

```
sheets = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
col_list = []
dup_list = []

for i in sheets:
    col_list.append(i.columns.values)
    for c in col_list:
        if c.duplicated():
            dup_list.append(c)
```

I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'duplicated'

I know there is no method for duplicated. What is the best way to get the duplicated column names that appear in all dataframes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `set.intersection` with mapped all columns names to `set`s:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('acbd'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abde'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('cbad'))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('acbf'))

sheets = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
L = [x.columns for x in sheets]
#less readable
#L = [x for x in sheets]
dup_list  = list(set.intersection(*map(set,L)))
print (dup_list)
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael, this is helpful thank you. However its returning an empty list

Comment: @Paul - hmmm,  try test only 2-3 DataFrames, in my opinion in real data not exist same columns in all `sheetnames` :( Or maybe some whitespaces? Is possible see `L = [x.columns for x in sheets]` `print (L)` ?

Comment: Print(L) Returns 4 arrays of the Column headers. Definately no white space. As I am able to create the merge with the following code manually:

`code`>client_merger = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['PAY REFERENCE', 'NAME'], left_index=True)

Comment: @Paul - Do you need all columns names which are same in each of Dataframe like in my answer? Or something else?

Comment: Yea so all of the column names that appear in each of the Dataframe (Which are duplicates) , these columns names should be what I merge the Dataframes on.

Comment: So if test `L = [x.columns[x.columns.isin(['PAY REFERENCE', 'NAME'])] for x in sheets]` what is `print (L)` ?

Comment: Think its nearly there, so returns https://pastebin.com/pHMnFAMa, one of the Dataframes doesnt contain this header. I tried then with the other 3 dataframes with your inital answer and works.

How would I go about including this then, even if one dataframe doesnt contain that column name

Comment: So, including it if its a duplicate in at least one of the Dataframes

Comment: @Paul - In my opinion if need working with DataFrame with no header later, still is necessary set them - e.g. manually by `df4.columns = ['cola1','col2',...]`. And then better is use `concat` like `merge` - Use `dfs = [x.set_index(dup_list) for x in sheets]` with `df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: @jezreal, Thank you, I will look into it